# How to delete one entry from a set which is a child of a document object?

Tags: mongodb

For example, we have documents in collection test.

```
>> db.test.find()
{ name: abc,  child: [ {name: child1, age:10}, 
                       {name: child2, age:20}, 
                       {name: child3, age:30} ]}

{ name: abcd, child: [ {name: child1, age:10}, 
                       {name: child2, age:20}, 
                       {name: child3, age:30} ]}
```

I want to delete the one with age equals 10 from child set in first document. How can I do it?
The expected result should be:

```
{ name: abc,  child: [ {name: child2, age:20}, 
                       {name: child3, age:30} ]}

{ name: abcd, child: [ {name: child1, age:10}, 
                       {name: child2, age:20}, 
                       {name: child3, age:30} ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use `update` with `$pull`;

```js
db.test.update({name:'abc'}, {$pull: {'child': {'age':10}}})
```

Demo;

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52034a77a45fcb007cbab9ac"), "name" : "abc", 
      "child" : [{ "name" : "child1", "age" : 10 },     
                 { "name" : "child2", "age" : 20 },
                 { "name" : "child3", "age" : 30 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52034a7aa45fcb007cbab9ad"), "name" : "abcd", 
      "child" : [ { "name" : "child1", "age" : 10 },
                  { "name" : "child2", "age" : 20 },
                  { "name" : "child3", "age" : 30 } ] }

> db.test.update({name:'abc'}, {$pull: {'child': {'age':10}}})
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52034a77a45fcb007cbab9ac"), "name" : "abc", 
      "child" : [{ "name" : "child2", "age" : 20 },
                 { "name" : "child3", "age" : 30 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52034a7aa45fcb007cbab9ad"), "name" : "abcd", 
      "child" : [ { "name" : "child1", "age" : 10 },
                  { "name" : "child2", "age" : 20 },
                  { "name" : "child3", "age" : 30 } ] }
```

EDIT: As to your question in the comment, here's how to set a comment on the age 30 child of 'abcd';

```
db.test.update({name:'abcd', 'child.age':30}, 
               {$set: {'child.$.comment': 'nothing'}})
```

Comment: How to update part of child? If I expect to get: { "_id" : ObjectId("52034a77a45fcb007cbab9ac"), "name" : "abc", 
      "child" : [{ "name" : "child2", "age" : 20 },
                 { "name" : "child3", "age" : 30 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52034a7aa45fcb007cbab9ad"), "name" : "abcd", 
      "child" : [ { "name" : "child1", "age" : 10 },
                  { "name" : "child2", "age" : 20 },
                  { "name" : "child3", "age" : 30, comment: 'nothing' } ] } . How to do it?

Comment: @user2663484 Added that to the answer. If you need more help, please create a new question since that tends to give the questions more attention than updating one.